# How to read in all text files from UNIX bash directory in Cloudera's Python API

Tags: python, text-mining, map-reduce

I'm still pretty new to Cloudera and using the UNIX environment. I have written a mapper that reads in .txt files from a directory in my Windows system, which works just fine. I read files in like this:

```
import glob
files = glob.glob("*.txt")
```

Is there an equivalent way to do this in the UNIX environment? I know I can read in one file by

```
infile=sys.stdin
```

but as far as reading all in from one directory I'm not sure.

Thanks!

Comment: `glob.glob("*.txt")` will work identically for both Windows and UNIX OS.

Comment: I probably have to pip install it first. The problem is, I try to install pip on the Cloudera VM running on my windows desktop, and the tricks for doing that in Unix that I see aren't working for me.

Comment: Python comes with a library of standard modules and `glob` is one of them. So you don't need to install it... PS your question is not very clear - what are you trying to achieve and how exactly it's not working?

Comment: I'm running Cloudera training VM 4.2.1, it is a version of Linux, and I'm running everything from a bash shell. What I'm attempting to do is write map-reduce code to run Hadoop streaming jobs in a pseudo distributed setup. The whole thing feels foreign to me.